# Spring/JPA: composite Key find returns empty elements [{}]

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

I have build my data model using JPA and am using Hibernate's EntityManager to access the data. I am using this configuration for other classes and have had no problems.

The issue is that I created an entity with a composite primary key (the two keys are foreign keys) , adding elements works perfectly I checked it in database but I am not able to retrieve the populated row from database.

For example if I query  "FROM Referentiel" to return a list of all referentiels in the table, I get this `[{},{}]` my list.size() has the proper number of elements (2), but the elements are null.

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Et_referentiel")
public class Referentiel implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_projet")
    private Projet projet;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ressource")
    private Ressource ressource;


    @Column(name = "unite", nullable = false)
    private String unite;
```

}

here is my controller getList method:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/list", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE })
    public List<Referentiel> listReferentiel(@RequestBody Long idProjet) {

        List<Referentiel> referentiel = referentielService.listReferentiel(idProjet);
        return referentiel;
    }
```

and here is my dao methods:

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void ajouterReferentiel(Referentiel ref) {
        em.persist(ref);
        em.flush();

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Referentiel> listReferentiel(Long idProjet) {

        Query query = em.createQuery("Select r from Referentiel r where r.projet.idProjet=:arg1");
        query.setParameter("arg1", idProjet);
        em.flush();     
        List<Referentiel> resultList = query.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have json jar or dependency in your project ? do you added json converter into spring ? can you show how you configured your controller ?

Comment: My project works always perfectly , I have this problem only when I used composite key, It's not a configuration issue

Comment: is Projet  also Serializable ?

Comment: Yes it's serializable

Comment: Do you have a configured `@IdClass` for your composite key?

Comment: No , I just did as descripted above

Comment: I don't see a transaction, so I'd check that first you committed your inserts before trying to query for them.  Second, JPA requires a primary key class or embedded ID when using a composite key, which is missing in your description.  The pk class will just be used for find operations to hold the values from the two references marked as ID.

Comment: I would also recommend you turn on logging and check the SQL that is issued, and verify that it is correct and returns the expected results when you run it on your database directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a class representing your composite key:

```java
public class ReferentielId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private Long projet; // Same type than idProjet, same name than inside Referentiel
    private Long ressource; // Same type than idRessource (I guess), same name than inside Referentiel

    // Constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

And assign it to your entity having that composite key.

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(ReferentielId.class) // <- here
@Table(name = "Et_referentiel")
public class Referentiel implements Serializable {

    // ...
}
```

Notice that it is required to have a class representing your composite keys, even if that does not help in your problem.

Comment: when added the class I have this error while adding : "detached entity passed to persist: solubat.entity.etudeDeDossier.Projet;

Comment: @SuperGirl Did you configured a cascade on the `@ManyToOne(cascade = ...)` of `etudeDeDossier.Projet`? Try `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` instead.

Comment: still have the same error detached entity passed to persist:

Comment: Even if you put `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` for `Projet` on `Referentiel`?

Comment: yes I added it but I still have this second issue (detached)

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe add the code for the creation where it fails and the `Projet` entity. About the retrieving, does it works now?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: Add the code where it fails to create + the `Projet` entity in your question or create a new question about this new problem.